# UX Certification/Courses

Tags: usability, jobs, certification

I have a master's degree in Human-Computer Interaction. Now, I am working as a software developer and I am thinking of switching to working in the UX field. Does anyone know of practical UX courses that will increase my chance of getting a UX job? Are there any exams that I could take to get certified?

Comment: This question is very broad, there are probably thousands of courses. As you are a master of HCI I would say that should be all the certification you need.

Comment: @RobE I heard that the courses offered by "https://www.nngroup.com/ux-certification/" are good.

Comment: The one HCI program I'm familiar with is well-suited for a UX job. Could you describe the ways you feel your degree is insufficient?

Comment: You might also describe what kind of UX job you're looking for. It's a broad field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I recommend the Nielsen Norman Group's certification.

These guys are gods when it comes to UX and I've attended one of their sessions and it was a great experience.

More here: https://www.nngroup.com/ux-certification/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Tarek, NN/g is a great organization and I am thankful for the foundation they helped me built.

I would like to bring [Center Centre](http://centercentre.com/) to your attention, too. It looks like an amazing program that is well suited for people who switch careers to the field of UX.

Good luck!